# How to validate header parameters while calling REST services in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, rest

I want to validate header parameters that I am going to send while calling REST of spring MVC. The validating class should return JSon object depending on result of validation. how can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: I tried with PermissionController. but that only returns true or false based on validation. that controller is called by @PreAuthorized() annotation. But I want to return JSon as a result of validation.

Comment: What JSON do you want to return?

Comment: JSon containing status i.e; SUCCESS or ERROR and the error message.

Comment: does [this](http://www.jpalace.org/mvc/document/92/binding-and-validation-of-handler-parameters-in-spring-mvc-controllers) help you.

Comment: No. I solved my problem. I used Interceptors. I am checking request using them. Its working fine!